# Pyhon: Time processing diferences between multithreading strategys and normal execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have a complexy task that delay many minutes to execute on normal execution.
I think if I can use a multithreading or multiprocessing on python to execute it more faster.
I do a test that verify if a simple algorithm can execute more fast on differents multithearing strategys but the Normal execution without multithreading or multiprocessing are more faster.
Follow the test code:

```
import asyncio
import itertools as it
import os
import random
import time
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from datetime import datetime
import threading


async def asyofunc(data):
    for row in data:
       await asyncio.gather(makeitemAsync(row,4,8))

async def makeitemAsync(row, minimum, maximum):
    count = 0
    for n in row:
        if minimum <= n <= maximum:
            count = count + 1
            #print(count)

def makeitem(row, minimum, maximum):
    count = 0
    for n in row:
        if minimum <= n <= maximum:
            count = count + 1
            #print(count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    np.random.RandomState(100)
    arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=[2000, 5])
    data = arr.tolist()
    data[:5]

    #Time Execution normal
    time = datetime.now()
    [makeitem(n, 4,8) for n in data]
    print('Normal: ' + str(datetime.now() - time))

    #Time Execution with Threading
    time = datetime.now()
    [threading.Thread(target=makeitem, args=(n,4,8)) for n in data]
    print('Threading: ' + str(datetime.now() - time))

    #Time Execution with asyncio
    time = datetime.now()
    asyncio.run(asyofunc(data))
    print('Asyncio: ' + str(datetime.now() - time))

    #Time Execution with multiprocessing
    time = datetime.now()
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    results = [pool.apply(makeitem, args=(row, 4, 8)) for row in data]
    pool.close()
    print('Multiprocessing: ' + str(datetime.now() - time))
```

Outputs: 
Normal: 0:00:00.005996 
Threading: 0:00:00.087949 
Asyncio: 0:00:00.287834 
Multiprocessing: 0:00:03.220960

What I can do to multitasking were more faster than normal processing?

Comment: Maybe your *test* functions are too simple and don't accurately reflect the processing of your real functions - so the effect you see is due the time it takes to *spin-up* the multi-threading/processing code. Or maybe the method you use to determine execution time could be improved. Do some searches on the site regarding multi-whatever execution times - there are **numerous** Q&A's, reading those should give you an idea of the different strategies to use and when (or when not) to use them.

Comment: your `makeitem` function executes very quickly, so the added overhead of parallel processing is very significant compared to the possible benefit of speeding up computation. perhaps you meant to write `np.random.randint(0, 10, size=[5, 2000])` instead to make the computation take a bit longer?